# Trouble adding pin annotation to map

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, annotations, mapkit

I get the error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION for the last two lines of this function.

```
@IBAction func makeEvent(sender: UIButton)
    {
        self.pointAnnotation1 = MKPointAnnotation()
        self.pointAnnotation1.title = "Event"
        self.pointAnnotation1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.986, longitude: -78.945)
        self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.mapView?.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate
        self.mapView?.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)
    }
```

Comment: use pointAnnotation1 instead of pointAnnotation while instantiating MKPinAnnotationView and assigning centerCoordinate.

Comment: I'm still having the error on the last line @NaveenKumarHS

Comment: can you post your full code. It may help